# How to inject RoleManager<Role> to my class from Startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

How to inject RoleManager  to my class from startup.cs?
Here are my codes:
Here I want to receive the RoleManager CustomRoleRequirement.cs

```
    public class CustomRoleRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<CustomRoleRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        private readonly RoleManager<Role> _roleManager;
        public CustomRoleRequirement(RoleManager<Role> roleManager)
        {
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }
    }
```

And inject it from here Startup.cs

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AccountManager", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new CustomRoleRequirement()));
            });
```

Comment: Did you run that code? Did you get an error or something? It should work as-is

Answer (score 2):

Add `services.AddIdentity<...>` to your `Startup` class. It will be already there if you created the project using the template with Identity. Identity injects `RoleManager<TRole>` already.

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: I forgot to write that RoleManager is part of IdentityFramework, so thats why  it is automatically injected when you add Identity to services in Startup.

Comment: Sorry, I think I put the question wrong. 
How can I use the RoleManager <Role> in my class by passing it through the constructor? `new CustomRoleRequirement()`